# Launch Storyboard from Xamarin PCL using Dependency Injection Not Working

Tags: ios, xcode, xamarin, augmented-reality, wikitude

I'm using dependency injection to launch Wikitude from my PCL project.

I'm using the WikitudeSDKSample. I've integrated it and it compiles.
When I run it, it shows a blank white page with the VC name at the top. It never initializes the camera or the AR. No errors.

Here's what I got so far:

```
    [assembly: Xamarin.Forms.Dependency(typeof(AugmentedRealityImplementation))]
namespace UXDivers.Artina.Grial
{
    public class AugmentedRealityImplementation : IAugmentedReality
    {
        public AugmentedRealityImplementation() { }

        public void LaunchWikitude()
        {

        var storyboard = UIStoryboard.FromName("MainStoryboard_iPhone", null);
        var controller = storyboard.InstantiateViewController("StoryBoardViewController");

        var window = UIApplication.SharedApplication.KeyWindow;
        window.RootViewController = controller;
        window.MakeKeyAndVisible();

        }
    }
}
```

Here's the Wikitude View Controller Class

```
using System;
using CoreGraphics;

using Foundation;
using UIKit;
using CoreMedia;

using Wikitude.Architect;

namespace UXDivers.Artina.Grial
{
    public partial class ExampleArchitectViewDelegate : WTArchitectViewDelegate 
    {
        public override void InvokedURL(WTArchitectView architectView, NSUrl url)
        {
            Console.WriteLine ("architect view invoked url: " + url);
        }

        public override void DidFinishLoadNavigation(WTArchitectView architectView, WTNavigation navigation)
        {
            Console.WriteLine ("architect view loaded navigation: " + navigation.OriginalURL);
        }

        public override void DidFailToLoadNavigation(WTArchitectView architectView, WTNavigation navigation, NSError error)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("architect view failed to load navigation. " + error.LocalizedDescription);
        }
    }

    public partial class WikitudeSDKExampleViewController : UIViewController
    {

        private WTArchitectView architectView;
        private WTAuthorizationRequestManager authorizationRequestManager = new WTAuthorizationRequestManager ();
        private ExampleArchitectViewDelegate architectViewDelegate = new ExampleArchitectViewDelegate ();

        private WTNavigation loadingArchitectWorldNavigation = null;

        private bool authorized = false;


        public WikitudeSDKExampleViewController (IntPtr handle) : base (handle)
        {
        }

        public override void DidReceiveMemoryWarning ()
        {
            // Releases the view if it doesn't have a superview.
            base.DidReceiveMemoryWarning ();

            // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
        }

        #region View lifecycle

        public override void ViewDidLoad ()
        {
            base.ViewDidLoad ();
            // Perform any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

            this.architectView = new Wikitude.Architect.WTArchitectView ();
            this.architectView.Delegate = architectViewDelegate;
            this.architectView.ShouldAuthorizeRestrictedAPIs = false;
            this.View.AddSubview (this.architectView);
            this.architectView.TranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false;

            NSDictionary views = new NSDictionary (new NSString ("architectView"), architectView);
            this.View.AddConstraints (NSLayoutConstraint.FromVisualFormat("|[architectView]|", 0, null, views));
            this.View.AddConstraints (NSLayoutConstraint.FromVisualFormat("V:|[architectView]|", 0, null, views));

            architectView.SetLicenseKey ("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");

            NSNotificationCenter.DefaultCenter.AddObserver(UIApplication.DidBecomeActiveNotification, (notification) => {               
                StartAR();
            });

            NSNotificationCenter.DefaultCenter.AddObserver(UIApplication.WillResignActiveNotification, (notification) => {
                StopAR();
            });
        }

        public override void ViewWillAppear (bool animated)
        {
            base.ViewWillAppear (animated);
        }

        public override void ViewDidAppear (bool animated)
        {
            base.ViewDidAppear (animated);

            if (!authorizationRequestManager.RequestingRestrictedAppleiOSSDKAPIAuthorization)
            {
                NSOrderedSet<NSNumber> restrictedAppleiOSSKDAPIs = WTAuthorizationRequestManager.RestrictedAppleiOSSDKAPIAuthorizationsForRequiredFeatures(WTFeatures.WTFeature_ImageTracking);
                authorizationRequestManager.RequestRestrictedAppleiOSSDKAPIAuthorization(restrictedAppleiOSSKDAPIs, (bool success, NSError error) => {
                    authorized = success;
                    if (success)
                    {
                        StartAR();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        handleAuthorizationError(error);
                    }
                });
            }
        }

        public override void ViewWillDisappear (bool animated)
        {
            base.ViewWillDisappear (animated);
        }

        public override void ViewDidDisappear (bool animated)
        {
            base.ViewDidDisappear (animated);

            StopAR ();
        }

        #endregion

        #region Rotation

        public override void WillRotate(UIInterfaceOrientation toInterfaceOrientation, double duration)
        {
            base.WillRotate (toInterfaceOrientation, duration);

            architectView.SetShouldRotateToInterfaceOrientation (true, toInterfaceOrientation);
        }

        public override bool ShouldAutorotate()
        {
            return true;
        }

        public override UIInterfaceOrientationMask GetSupportedInterfaceOrientations ()
        {
            return UIInterfaceOrientationMask.All;
        }

        #endregion

        #region Segue
        [Action("UnwindToMainViewController")]
        public void UnwindToMainViewController()
        { 
        }
        #endregion

        #region Private Methods
        private void handleAuthorizationError(NSError authorizationError)
        {
            NSDictionary unauthorizedAPIInfo = (NSDictionary)authorizationError.UserInfo.ObjectForKey(WTAuthorizationRequestManager.WTUnauthorizedAppleiOSSDKAPIsKey);

            NSMutableString detailedAuthorizationErrorLogMessage = (NSMutableString)new NSString("The following authorization states do not meet the requirements:").MutableCopy();
            NSMutableString missingAuthorizations = (NSMutableString)new NSString("In order to use the Wikitude SDK, please grant access to the following:").MutableCopy();
            foreach (NSString unauthorizedAPIKey in unauthorizedAPIInfo.Keys)
            {
                NSNumber unauthorizedAPIValue = (NSNumber)unauthorizedAPIInfo.ObjectForKey(unauthorizedAPIKey);
                detailedAuthorizationErrorLogMessage.Append(new NSString("\n"));
                detailedAuthorizationErrorLogMessage.Append(unauthorizedAPIKey);
                detailedAuthorizationErrorLogMessage.Append(new NSString(" = "));
                detailedAuthorizationErrorLogMessage.Append(WTAuthorizationRequestManager.StringFromAuthorizationStatusForUnauthorizedAppleiOSSDKAPI(unauthorizedAPIValue.Int32Value, unauthorizedAPIKey));

                missingAuthorizations.Append(new NSString("\n *"));
                missingAuthorizations.Append(WTAuthorizationRequestManager.HumanReadableDescriptionForUnauthorizedAppleiOSSDKAPI(unauthorizedAPIKey));
            }
            Console.WriteLine(detailedAuthorizationErrorLogMessage);

            UIAlertController settingsAlertController = UIAlertController.Create("Required API authorizations missing", missingAuthorizations, UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert);
            settingsAlertController.AddAction(UIAlertAction.Create("Open Settings", UIAlertActionStyle.Default, (UIAlertAction obj) =>
            {
                UIApplication.SharedApplication.OpenUrl(new NSUrl(UIApplication.OpenSettingsUrlString));
            }));
            settingsAlertController.AddAction(UIAlertAction.Create("NO", UIAlertActionStyle.Destructive, (UIAlertAction obj) => { }));
            this.PresentViewController(settingsAlertController, true, null);
        }

        private void StartAR()
        {
            if (authorized)
            {
                if (!architectView.IsRunning)
                {
                    architectView.Start((startupConfiguration) =>
                    {
                        // use startupConfiguration.CaptureDevicePosition = AVFoundation.AVCaptureDevicePosition.Front; to start the Wikitude SDK with an active front cam
                        startupConfiguration.CaptureDevicePosition = AVFoundation.AVCaptureDevicePosition.Back;
                        startupConfiguration.CaptureDeviceResolution = WTCaptureDeviceResolution.WTCaptureDeviceResolution_AUTO;
                        startupConfiguration.TargetFrameRate = CMTime.PositiveInfinity; // resolves to WTMakeTargetFrameRateAuto();
                    }, (bool isRunning, NSError startupError) => {
                       if (isRunning)
                        {
                            if (null == loadingArchitectWorldNavigation)
                            {
                                var path = NSBundle.MainBundle.BundleUrl.AbsoluteString + "x_Demo_2_SolarSystem(Geo)/index.html";
                                loadingArchitectWorldNavigation = architectView.LoadArchitectWorldFromURL(NSUrl.FromString(path), Wikitude.Architect.WTFeatures.WTFeature_ImageTracking);
                            }

                       }
                       else
                       {
                           Console.WriteLine("Unable to start Wikitude SDK. Error (start ar): " + startupError.LocalizedDescription);
                       }
                   });
                }

                architectView.SetShouldRotateToInterfaceOrientation(true, UIApplication.SharedApplication.StatusBarOrientation);
            }
        }

        private void StopAR()
        {
            if (architectView.IsRunning)
            {
                architectView.Stop();
            }
        }
        #endregion
    }
}
```

Here's the iphone storyboard

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<document type="com.apple.InterfaceBuilder3.CocoaTouch.Storyboard.XIB" version="3.0" toolsVersion="4451" systemVersion="13A461" targetRuntime="iOS.CocoaTouch.iPad" propertyAccessControl="none" useAutolayout="YES" initialViewController="15">
    <dependencies>
        <plugIn identifier="com.apple.InterfaceBuilder.IBCocoaTouchPlugin" version="3733.0"/>
    </dependencies>
    <scenes>
        <!--class Prefix:identifier View Controller-->
        <scene sceneID="tne-QT-ifu">
            <objects>
                <viewController id="BYZ-38-t0r" customClass="WikitudeSDKExampleViewController" sceneMemberID="viewController">
                    <layoutGuides>
                        <viewControllerLayoutGuide type="top" id="3"/>
                        <viewControllerLayoutGuide type="bottom" id="4"/>
                    </layoutGuides>
                    <view key="view" contentMode="scaleToFill" id="8bC-Xf-vdC">
                        <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="64" width="768" height="960"/>
                        <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask" widthSizable="YES" heightSizable="YES"/>
                        <color key="backgroundColor" white="1" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="calibratedWhite"/>
                    </view>
                    <navigationItem title="Wikitude SDK" id="585" key="navigationItem">
                        <barButtonItem key="rightBarButtonItem" title="Info" id="588">
                            <connections>
                                <segue id="780" destination="599" kind="modal" modalPresentationStyle="formSheet"/>
                            </connections>
                            <color key="tintColor" colorSpace="calibratedRGB" red="1" green="0.49803921568627452" blue="0" alpha="1"/>
                        </barButtonItem>
                    </navigationItem>
                    <extendedEdge key="edgesForExtendedLayout" bottom="YES"/>
                </viewController>
                <placeholder placeholderIdentifier="IBFirstResponder" id="dkx-z0-nzr" sceneMemberID="firstResponder"/>
            </objects>
            <point key="canvasLocation" x="-333" y="-299"/>
        </scene>
        <scene sceneID="14">
            <objects>
                <navigationController id="15" sceneMemberID="viewController">
                    <navigationBar key="navigationBar" contentMode="scaleToFill" id="17">
                        <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="20" width="768" height="44"/>
                        <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask"/>
                    </navigationBar>
                    <connections>
                        <segue id="586" destination="BYZ-38-t0r" kind="relationship" relationship="rootViewController"/>
                    </connections>
                </navigationController>
                <placeholder placeholderIdentifier="IBFirstResponder" id="18" userLabel="First Responder" sceneMemberID="firstResponder"/>
            </objects>
            <point key="canvasLocation" x="-1230" y="-294"/>
        </scene>
        <scene sceneID="589">
            <objects>
                <tableViewController id="590" sceneMemberID="viewController" customClass="WTSDKInformationViewController">
                    <tableView key="view" clipsSubviews="YES" contentMode="scaleToFill" alwaysBounceVertical="YES" dataMode="static" style="grouped" separatorStyle="default" rowHeight="44" sectionHeaderHeight="28" sectionFooterHeight="28" id="592">
                        <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="768" height="1024"/>
                        <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask" widthSizable="YES" heightSizable="YES"/>
                        <color key="backgroundColor" white="1" alpha="1" colorSpace="calibratedWhite"/>
                        <connections>
                            <outlet property="dataSource" destination="590" id="593"/>
                            <outlet property="delegate" destination="590" id="594"/>
                        </connections>
                        <sections>
                            <tableViewSection headerTitle="SDK Information" id="605">
                                <cells>
                                    <tableViewCell clipsSubviews="YES" contentMode="scaleToFill" selectionStyle="default" indentationWidth="10" id="606" rowHeight="44" style="IBUITableViewCellStyleValue1" textLabel="1061" detailTextLabel="1062">
                                        <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="55.5" width="768" height="44"/>
                                        <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask"/>
                                        <tableViewCellContentView key="contentView" opaque="NO" clipsSubviews="YES" multipleTouchEnabled="YES" contentMode="center" tableViewCell="606" id="607">
                                            <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="768" height="43.5"/>
                                            <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask"/>
                                            <subviews>
                                                <label opaque="NO" multipleTouchEnabled="YES" contentMode="left" text="Version Number:" textAlignment="natural" lineBreakMode="tailTruncation" baselineAdjustment="alignBaselines" adjustsFontSizeToFit="NO" id="1061">
                                                    <rect key="frame" x="48" y="12" width="128" height="20.5"/>
                                                    <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask"/>
                                                    <fontDescription key="fontDescription" type="system" pointSize="17"/>
                                                    <color key="textColor" cocoaTouchSystemColor="darkTextColor"/>
                                                    <nil key="highlightedColor"/>
                                                </label>
                                                <label opaque="NO" multipleTouchEnabled="YES" contentMode="left" text="Subtitle" textAlignment="right" lineBreakMode="tailTruncation" baselineAdjustment="alignBaselines" adjustsFontSizeToFit="NO" id="1062">
                                                    <rect key="frame" x="661" y="12" width="59" height="20.5"/>
                                                    <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask"/>
                                                    <fontDescription key="fontDescription" type="system" pointSize="17"/>
                                                    <nil key="textColor"/>
                                                    <nil key="highlightedColor"/>
                                                </label>
                                            </subviews>
                                        </tableViewCellContentView>
                                    </tableViewCell>
                                </cells>
                            </tableViewSection>
                            <tableViewSection headerTitle="Build Information" id="612">
                                <cells>
                                    <tableViewCell clipsSubviews="YES" contentMode="scaleToFill" selectionStyle="default" indentationWidth="10" id="613" rowHeight="44" style="IBUITableViewCellStyleValue1" textLabel="1063" detailTextLabel="1064">
                                        <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="293" width="768" height="44"/>
                                        <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask"/>
                                        <tableViewCellContentView key="contentView" opaque="NO" clipsSubviews="YES" multipleTouchEnabled="YES" contentMode="center" tableViewCell="613" id="614">
                                            <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="768" height="43.5"/>
                                            <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask"/>
                                            <subviews>
                                                <label opaque="NO" multipleTouchEnabled="YES" contentMode="left" text="Build Date:" textAlignment="natural" lineBreakMode="tailTruncation" baselineAdjustment="alignBaselines" adjustsFontSizeToFit="NO" id="1063">
                                                    <rect key="frame" x="48" y="12" width="83.5" height="20.5"/>
                                                    <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask"/>
                                                    <fontDescription key="fontDescription" type="system" pointSize="17"/>
                                                    <color key="textColor" cocoaTouchSystemColor="darkTextColor"/>
                                                    <nil key="highlightedColor"/>
                                                </label>
                                                <label opaque="NO" multipleTouchEnabled="YES" contentMode="left" text="Subtitle" textAlignment="right" lineBreakMode="tailTruncation" baselineAdjustment="alignBaselines" adjustsFontSizeToFit="NO" id="1064">
                                                    <rect key="frame" x="661" y="12" width="59" height="20.5"/>
                                                    <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask"/>
                                                    <fontDescription key="fontDescription" type="system" pointSize="17"/>
                                                    <nil key="textColor"/>
                                                    <nil key="highlightedColor"/>
                                                </label>
                                            </subviews>
                                        </tableViewCellContentView>
                                    </tableViewCell>
                                    <tableViewCell clipsSubviews="YES" contentMode="scaleToFill" selectionStyle="default" indentationWidth="10" id="615" rowHeight="44" style="IBUITableViewCellStyleValue1" textLabel="1065" detailTextLabel="1066">
                                        <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="337" width="768" height="44"/>
                                        <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask"/>
                                        <tableViewCellContentView key="contentView" opaque="NO" clipsSubviews="YES" multipleTouchEnabled="YES" contentMode="center" tableViewCell="615" id="616">
                                            <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="768" height="43.5"/>
                                            <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask"/>
                                            <subviews>
                                                <label opaque="NO" multipleTouchEnabled="YES" contentMode="left" text="Build Number:" textAlignment="natural" lineBreakMode="tailTruncation" baselineAdjustment="alignBaselines" adjustsFontSizeToFit="NO" id="1065">
                                                    <rect key="frame" x="48" y="12" width="109" height="20.5"/>
                                                    <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask"/>
                                                    <fontDescription key="fontDescription" type="system" pointSize="17"/>
                                                    <color key="textColor" cocoaTouchSystemColor="darkTextColor"/>
                                                    <nil key="highlightedColor"/>
                                                </label>
                                                <label opaque="NO" multipleTouchEnabled="YES" contentMode="left" text="Subtitle" textAlignment="right" lineBreakMode="tailTruncation" baselineAdjustment="alignBaselines" adjustsFontSizeToFit="NO" id="1066">
                                                    <rect key="frame" x="661" y="12" width="59" height="20.5"/>
                                                    <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask"/>
                                                    <fontDescription key="fontDescription" type="system" pointSize="17"/>
                                                    <nil key="textColor"/>
                                                    <nil key="highlightedColor"/>
                                                </label>
                                            </subviews>
                                        </tableViewCellContentView>
                                    </tableViewCell>
                                    <tableViewCell clipsSubviews="YES" contentMode="scaleToFill" selectionStyle="default" indentationWidth="10" id="617" rowHeight="44" style="IBUITableViewCellStyleValue1" textLabel="1067" detailTextLabel="1068">
                                        <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="381" width="768" height="44"/>
                                        <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask"/>
                                        <tableViewCellContentView key="contentView" opaque="NO" clipsSubviews="YES" multipleTouchEnabled="YES" contentMode="center" tableViewCell="617" id="618">
                                            <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="768" height="43.5"/>
                                            <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask"/>
                                            <subviews>
                                                <label opaque="NO" multipleTouchEnabled="YES" contentMode="left" text="Build Configuration:" textAlignment="natural" lineBreakMode="tailTruncation" baselineAdjustment="alignBaselines" adjustsFontSizeToFit="NO" id="1067">
                                                    <rect key="frame" x="48" y="12" width="151" height="20.5"/>
                                                    <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask"/>
                                                    <fontDescription key="fontDescription" type="system" pointSize="17"/>
                                                    <color key="textColor" cocoaTouchSystemColor="darkTextColor"/>
                                                    <nil key="highlightedColor"/>
                                                </label>
                                                <label opaque="NO" multipleTouchEnabled="YES" contentMode="left" text="Subtitle" textAlignment="right" lineBreakMode="tailTruncation" baselineAdjustment="alignBaselines" adjustsFontSizeToFit="NO" id="1068">
                                                    <rect key="frame" x="661" y="12" width="59" height="20.5"/>
                                                    <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask"/>
                                                    <fontDescription key="fontDescription" type="system" pointSize="17"/>
                                                    <nil key="textColor"/>
                                                    <nil key="highlightedColor"/>
                                                </label>
                                            </subviews>
                                        </tableViewCellContentView>
                                    </tableViewCell>
                                </cells>
                            </tableViewSection>
                        </sections>
                        <color key="separatorColor" colorSpace="calibratedRGB" red="1" green="0.49803921568627452" blue="0" alpha="1"/>
                    </tableView>
                    <navigationItem key="navigationItem" title="Wikitude Xamarin Component" id="591">
                        <barButtonItem key="rightBarButtonItem" id="619" style="done" systemItem="done">
                            <color key="tintColor" colorSpace="calibratedRGB" red="1" green="0.49803921568627452" blue="0" alpha="1"/>
                            <connections>
                                <segue id="1059" destination="603" kind="unwind" unwindAction="UnwindToMainViewController"/>
                            </connections>
                        </barButtonItem>
                    </navigationItem>
                </tableViewController>
                <placeholder placeholderIdentifier="IBFirstResponder" id="597" userLabel="First Responder" sceneMemberID="firstResponder"/>
                <exit id="603" userLabel="Exit" sceneMemberID="exit"/>
            </objects>
            <point key="canvasLocation" x="665" y="-1542"/>
        </scene>
        <scene sceneID="598">
            <objects>
                <navigationController id="599" sceneMemberID="viewController">
                    <navigationBar key="navigationBar" contentMode="scaleToFill" id="601">
                        <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="20" width="768" height="44"/>
                        <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask"/>
                    </navigationBar>
                    <connections>
                        <segue destination="590" kind="relationship" relationship="rootViewController" id="600"/>
                    </connections>
                </navigationController>
                <placeholder placeholderIdentifier="IBFirstResponder" id="602" userLabel="First Responder" sceneMemberID="firstResponder"/>
            </objects>
            <point key="canvasLocation" x="-317" y="-1541"/>
        </scene>
    </scenes>
    <simulatedMetricsContainer key="defaultSimulatedMetrics">
        <simulatedStatusBarMetrics key="statusBar" statusBarStyle="blackOpaque"/>
        <simulatedOrientationMetrics key="orientation"/>
        <simulatedScreenMetrics key="destination"/>
    </simulatedMetricsContainer>
    <resources>
        <image name="Default-568h.png" width="320" height="568"/>
        <image name="1_ImageRecognition_1_ImageOnTarget/assets/imageOne.png" width="446" height="1024"/>
        <image name="1_ImageRecognition_1_ImageOnTarget/assets/surfer.png" width="38" height="50"/>
    </resources>
</document>
```

Comment: Did you already set a breakpoint in `StartAR` to check how far you come inside this method? A white or black view means that the Wikitude SDK is not started.

Comment: Yes I figured that. The Wikitude class was not linked up in the designer well. I deleted everything and recreated it.

Answer (score 0):

I deleted everything and recreated it and it worked with following code:

```
    'public void LaunchWikitude()
    {

    var storyboard = UIStoryboard.FromName("MainStoryboard_iPhone", null);
    var controller = storyboard.InstantiateViewController("StoryBoardViewController") as UIViewController;

    var window = UIApplication.SharedApplication.KeyWindow;
    window.RootViewController = controller;
    window.MakeKeyAndVisible();

    }'
```